# Convert signed int to string ip address in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ip-address

I'm retrieving a signed int from a SQL Server database and need to convert it to a "normal" looking dotted string for display to users.

Googling, I found this code:

```
SELECT 
   dbo.IPADDRESS.IPADDRESS,
   CAST(ROUND( (cast(dbo.IPADDRESS.IPADDRESS as bigint) / 16777216 ), 0, 1) AS varchar(4)) + '.' +
   CAST((ROUND( (cast(dbo.IPADDRESS.IPADDRESS as bigint) / 65536 ), 0, 1) % 256) AS varchar(4)) + '.' +
   CAST((ROUND( (cast(dbo.IPADDRESS.IPADDRESS as bigint) / 256 ), 0, 1) % 256) AS varchar(4)) + '.' + 
   CAST((cast(dbo.IPADDRESS.IPADDRESS as bigint) % 256 ) AS varchar(4)) as IPDottedNotation
FROM  
   dbo.IPADDRESS
```

which works some of the time, but produces wacky output other times.  For example, converting this `-1951276725` yields the result `-116.-78.-30.-181`.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DECLARE @IPADDRESS TABLE (
  IPADDRESS INT);

INSERT INTO @IPADDRESS
VALUES      (-1139627840),
            ( 1);

SELECT 
        LTRIM(CAST(SUBSTRING(IP,4,1) AS TINYINT)) + '.' + 
        LTRIM(CAST(SUBSTRING(IP,3,1) AS TINYINT)) + '.' + 
        LTRIM(CAST(SUBSTRING(IP,2,1) AS TINYINT)) + '.' + 
        LTRIM(CAST(SUBSTRING(IP,1,1) AS TINYINT))
FROM @IPADDRESS
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(IPADDRESS AS BINARY(4))) C(IP)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm an MSSQL newbie and I'm struggling to understand what's going on here.  Is anyone willing to "talk" me through.

Comment: @jalperin The `CROSS APPLY` casts the 4 byte integer to a 4 byte binary. The result of that expression is then aliased as `IP`. This is simply to avoid needing to repeat the cast to binary four separate times. The `SUBSTRING(IP,1,1)` extracts the first byte from that, `SUBSTRING(IP,2,1)` the second and so on. This will be in the range `0x00` to `0xFF` the cast to `tinyint` converts that to decimal form. The `LTRIM` is used to cast the result to string so that it can be concatenated together into the dotted form. More concise than `CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(IP,1,1) AS TINYINT) AS VARCHAR(3))`

Comment: @MartinSmith Great explanation; thank you!  Just one more point:  So this entire statement can be plugged into my actual SELECT?  (I'm accustomed to seeing FROM always being used with a table name, so the use of a column name there confused me.)

Comment: @jalperin - Yes, the `FROM dbo.IPADDRESS` is the reference to your actual table. The `SELECT` in the `CROSS APPLY` references the column from that.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for negative/signed integer ip values.

Comment: @CaMiX In what sense? The example in the OP is negative and it will have worked for that or it wouldn't have been accepted.

Comment: @CaMiX - Ah I see your point. The octets need to be displayed in a different order if negative. Fixed.

Comment: This code will break if IPADDRESS is a valid BIGINT

Answer (score 3):

The code you have would work if `IPADDRESS` was a bigint (effectively storing the unsigned int representation in the database - i.e. all values > 0). Do you have the option of changing the datatype in the table?

To get what you have to work, you need to convert your signed int to the equivalent unsigned int before the conversion to bigint. I'm not sure what the most efficient way to do this in TSQL is, but it might be to cast it to binary:

```
SELECT dbo.IPADDRESS.IPADDRESS,
CAST(ROUND( (cast(cast(dbo.IPADDRESS.IPADDRESS as binary(4)) as bigint) / 16777216 ), 0, 1) AS varchar(4)) + '.' +
CAST((ROUND( (cast(cast(dbo.IPADDRESS.IPADDRESS as binary(4)) as bigint) / 65536 ), 0, 1) % 256) AS varchar(4)) + '.' +
CAST((ROUND( (cast(cast(dbo.IPADDRESS.IPADDRESS as binary(4)) as bigint) / 256 ), 0, 1) % 256) AS varchar(4)) + '.' + 
CAST((cast(cast(dbo.IPADDRESS.IPADDRESS as binary(4)) as bigint) % 256 ) AS varchar(4)) as IPDottedNotation
```

Comment: IP bytes are for some reason inverted in my case, but no problem. Works great

Answer (score 1):

Like @Ed Harper stated that the selected solution doesn't work for a signed int. Below is my solution which requires a little less casting and isn't inverted. Check out the following test scenario shown below where the converted string/varchar IP should be 192.168.18.188:

```
CREATE TABLE #data
  (
     ip     NVARCHAR(45),
     before NVARCHAR(45)
  )

INSERT INTO #data
VALUES     ('converted-ip','-1139627840')

    update #data
    set ip = cast((cast(before as int) & 255) as nvarchar) + '.' +
         cast((cast(floor(convert(decimal, before)/256) as int) & 255) as nvarchar) + '.' +
         cast((cast(floor(convert(decimal, before)/65536) as int) & 255) as nvarchar) + '.' +
         cast((cast(floor(convert(decimal, before)/16777216) as int) & 255) as nvarchar)

select * from #data
```