# Issue with a SQL query to find Blacklisted Software within SCCM

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ip-address

Good Morning

I've been asked to write a report in a production environment, so show if any clients have any blacklisted software.

I've managed to get the report working, with a SQL query.  The issue I have now, is they want me to include the IP address of the Client.

What I have so far is:

```
select distinct b.name0 as [Computer Name], b.ResourceID as [GetCurrentIP],
       b.User_name0 as [Last Log on User],  c.Caption0 as [Operating System],
       a.displayname0 as [Installed Application], a.Publisher0 as [Publisher],
       a.version0 as [Version]
from V_add_remove_programs as a 
join V_R_System as b on a.resourceid = b.resourceid
join V_GS_Operating_system as c on a.resourceid = c.resourceid
```

With the b.ResourceID as [GetCurrentIP] included, I get the following information returned:  16781920, which I'm aware is not a valid IP.

Is there a way I can get the valid IP address through SQL.

Many Thanks for your help

Comment: Where are the valid IP addresses stored?

Comment: At the moment I'm trying the query within SQL 2014 Management Studio.

Comment: The Valid IP is seen within dbo.AMT_MachineProperties.  I have tried adding this into the query, but it's errors, with a Multi-part Identifier, could not be bound.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696008/spliting-string-using-sql-statement-ip-address/29700809#29700809) answer demonstrates converting between integers and dotted IPV4 addresses.

Answer (score 1):

The integer you are returning is, in fact, probably an IP address, just stored as an int.

You can [convert integers to IP addresses in your query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177607/convert-signed-int-to-string-ip-address-in-sql-server), assuming your DBMS allows string manipulation.